# Material UI Table component is not playing nice with Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, material-ui

**Versions**
Material-UI: *0.18.0*
React: *15.5.4*
Redux: *3.6.0*
Browser: *Chrome -- Version 59.0.3071.115 (Official Build) (64-bit)*

**Problem**
I am using redux for application wide state management instead of setState. When calling redux actions the checkbox doesn't register as checked, but it registers that it was clicked when I console.log the `onRowSelection`. If I remove the line calling my action, the checkboxes work just fine. For some reason, Material UI is blocked from updating when I call my redux action.

***--Edit--***
It appears that it's not the action that is causing the malfunction it's something about my reducer that material UI's Table doesn't like.
(added reducer snippet below)

**Table Component**

```
class AdminDeptAppAccess extends React.Component {

  _onRowSelection (selectedUsers, props) {
    console.log(selectedUsers)
    props.selectedUsersAction(filterUsers(selectedUsers, props.deptAppRoles))
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <Table
        selectable
        multiSelectable
        onRowSelection={(selectedUsers) => this._onRowSelection(selectedUsers, this.props)}
       >
         {/* contents */}
       </Table>
    )
  }
}

const filterUsers = (selectedUsers, deptAppRoles) => {
  if (selectedUsers === 'all') {
    return deptAppRoles
  } else if (selectedUsers === 'none') {
    return []
  } else if (selectedUsers === []) {
    return []
  } else {
    let users = []
    selectedUsers.map((num, i) => (
      users.push(deptAppRoles[num])
    ))
    return users
  }
}
```

**applicable redux action that was passed down via props**

```
export const selectedUsersAction = (users) => {
  console.log('selectedUsersAction', users)
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch({
      type: 'SELECTED_USERS',
      selectedUsers: users
    })
  }
}
```

***applicable reducer***

```
const admin = (state = { selectedUsers: [] }, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    // ...
    case 'SELECTED_USERS':
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        selectedUsers: action.selectedUsers
      })
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

**screenshot**
ignore the console errors, they are from something else.

I selected the first row, and the console registers that [0] was clicked, and my redux action registers who got clicked, but the checkbox doesn't update because my redux action (reducer) somehow blocked the component from rendering the updated checkbox.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that your reducer is working with an immutable state (by using `Object.assign`). This is a good way to write a reducer (or using spread notation), but it's causing a problem here.

When you set the new `selectedUsers` in the reducer you are also creating a new copy of state and replacing the old one. I'm guessing you are storing the actual data used to generate the table in same reducer as the `selectedUsers` (an array of user objects?). When you use `Object.assign({}, state, etc....` you are creating new instances of every property on the state object. This includes the array of user objects used to generate the table rows.

The table component must be registering that this array is new and forcing a re-render or clearing the current selected state based on the fact that the array has been replaced.

I had the same problem and I started off with this fix -

```
const admin = (state = { selectedUsers: [] }, action) => {
 switch (action.type) {
  // ...
  case 'SELECTED_USERS':
   state.selectedUsers = action.selectedUsers
   return state
  default:
   return state
 }
}
```

It worked, but I didn't like it.
So I opted to store my `selectedUsers` in a separate reducer to the actual user data used to generate the table and that also fixed my problem. It's not the best fix in the world, but it works and it's better than sacrificing immutability.

So for the time being I have a separate `selected` reducer for my different table views. I think I'll need to find a better solution in the long run.

Comment: great explanation, totally understand now!